# Ruby on Rails Installation - Fedora 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm having some issues installing Rails. I have no experience with Ruby on Rails and am trying to install it on my Linux box (Fedora 7). I am following the instructions on: http://rubyonrails.org/download

I installed Ruby and it seemed to install without error. I built it manually from the source `ruby-1.8.7-p174.tar.gz` package.

```
[root@localhost ~]# which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
[root@localhost ~]# echo $PATH
...:/usr/local/bin:...
[root@localhost ~]# ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-linux]
```

So that appeared to go fine. The next step as I understand is to install RubyGems and then install Rails. So I downloaded the RubyGems source (rubygems-1.3.7.tgz) and ran that

```
[root@localhost ~]# ruby setup.rb
...
RubyGems installed the following executables:
/usr/local/bin/gem
```

Appeared to install correctly. `/usr/local/bin` is in the path, so installing Rails should be as simple as `gem install rails`, right?

```
[root@localhost ~]# gem install rails
ERROR: Loading command: install (LoadError)
    no such file to load -- zlib
Error: While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
```

No clue what this error is trying to tell me. Any ideas? I did a little poking around and saw some similar, but not identical errors. People were instructed to install zlib. Well, I already have zlib and zlib-devel installed on this system.

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -q zlib zlib-devel
zlib-1.2.3-10.fc7
zlib-devel-1.2.3-10.fc7
```

Does anyone more familiar with the gem package manager know what I'm missing here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have not compiled ruby with zlib.

Resource: http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/153-Compiling-Ruby-with-OpenSSL-Zlib-and-Readline-support-on-Debian

Answer (score 2):

While on a technical level, the issue is a missing flag from the your ruby compilation, on a more practical level I have to question why the heck you are running Fedora 7.  This is a May 2007 release we're talking about that has been past End of Life for over 2 years.

In a modern Fedora system (e.g. Fedora 14, released in the past month) you install Rails with the following line:

```
$ yum install rubygem-rails
```

Comment: Agreed.  Fedora is NOT the right distrib to use if you're not interested in moving forward...